# Comportamiento raro con multiples input type="time" agregados dinamicamente

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy usando el control `input type="time"` varias veces de forma dinámica, empiezo a describir mi problema. 
Cuando agrego un control `input type="time"` por primera vez, todo funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando agrego 2 o más controles `input type="time"`, la propiedad `focus` se centra solo en ultimo elemento `input type="time"` agregado, no teniendo acceso a los elementos agregados previamente, este el el código que uso:

```
// Funcion que agrega controles input type="time" dinamicamente
function check(obj) {

if( $(obj).is(':checked')){    
    var row = $(obj).val();        

    var cont = $('#Matinees tr.selected').find("td:nth-child(3) input[type*='time']").length;
    if(cont == 0){
        cont = row+'2';
    }else{
        cont = row+''+cont;
    }

    var del = '<img id="delHour'+cont+'" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="img/remove-button.svg" width="25" height="25">'; 

    $('<div id="div'+row+'" class="row" style="position: relative;">'+
        '<div class="col-md-5" style="display:inline-block;width:210px;">'+
          '<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="You must put an hour">'+
          '<input class="input100" type="time" id="time'+cont+'" name="time'+cont+'" min="9:00" max="22:00" />'+
          '<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Escoge una hora"></span></div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="col-md-3" style="display:inline-block; padding-top:15px; float: right; ">'+
            del +
        '</div>'+
     '</div>').appendTo("#container"+row+"");  

    setTimeout( function() {
        $(obj).prop('checked', false);
    }, 800 );

 }

 return true;

}  

[Añado una imagen][1]
```

[image: Comportamiento raro :/]

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema es que todos los INPUTs quedan con el mismo Id.
Prueba de cambiar la cuarta linea por esta, para que encuentre los INPUTs y les ponga otro nombre:

```
var cont = $("#container" + row + " input[type='time']").length;
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Ya probe tu código, hace lo mismo exactamente, ya verifique y no tienen el mismo nombre, cada elemento tiene su propio ID, gracias por tu comentario y saludos!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví, ;) lo que afectaba era un una función creada por mi, comente dos lineas que estaban creando el comportamiento raro, dejo el código y saludos!!!

```
 // Put the CLASS for row selection in the table #Matinees
$("#Matinees").on('click','tr',function(){
    // // Put the CLASS for row selection in the table #tableCinemaShows, also put focus and select on quantity input text
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
//   Aquí     $(this).find("td:nth-child(3) input[type='time']").focus();
//   Aquí     $(this).find("td:nth-child(3) input[type='time']").select();
});
```